# FBSDK does not allow to sign in with a different account after logging out

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

`i have integrate fb login in react native its working fine but i am  logout and comeback again not showing user name and password screen`

`import {LoginManager} from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';

const handleLogout = async () => {
await LoginManager.logOut();
};`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yARGb.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need logout after not come to facebook login screen its come to signed screen
i have mention to image link https://aboutreact.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/fblogin_example7-473x1024.png